# tesseract not able to detect korean language properly

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am learning how to detect Korean text, for sample I am using Korean text present in back of package, but pytesseract.image_to_string(img_pl,lang='kor') is not able to segregate words separately when I query with level set to word
Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import PIL
import pytesseract
import html
import io
import os
img_cv2 = cv2.imread('/Users/aniketdeshmukh/Desktop/Korean Text Images/0.png')
img_pl = PIL.Image.open('/Users/aniketdeshmukh/Desktop/Korean Text Images/0.png')
text_pl = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_cv2,lang='kor')
text_pl = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_pl,lang='kor')

#print(text_pl)
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img_pl,lang='kor')
dataList = list(map(lambda x: x.split('\t'),data.split('\n')))
df = pd.DataFrame(dataList[1:],columns=dataList[0])
#df
df.info
df.dropna(inplace=True)
col_int = ['level','page_num','block_num','par_num','line_num','word_num','left','top','width','height','conf']
df[col_int] = df[col_int].astype(int)
img_cv2 = cv2.imread('/Users/aniketdeshmukh/Desktop/Korean Text Images/0.png')
image = img_cv2.copy()
level = 'word'
for l,x,y,w,h,c in df[['level','left','top','width','height','conf']].values:
    if level == 'page':
        if l == 1:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,0),2)
        else:
            continue
    elif level == 'block':
        if l == 2:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        else:
            continue
    elif level == 'para':
        if l == 3:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        else:
            continue
    elif level == 'line':
        if l == 4:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        else:
            continue
    elif level == 'word':
        if l == 5:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        else:
            continue

cv2.imshow("bounding box",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output I get is following even when level is set to 'word'

[image: I am expecting all words to be higlighted properly but some are missing as below]

Comment: You haven't asked any question here. I supposed your question is how to get Tesseract to read work better with Hangul? From my own researches and experimens Tesseract is known to be not efficient at reading Hangul. No matter the trick you use it will not work well in the current state of things.